# Thread doesn't print sequential order

Tags: c#, multithreading

This code does not print number in sequential order as expected, like this:

```
012345678910
```

What's the problem ?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;    
            new Thread(() => Console.Write(temp)).Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I really, really, really don't understand what you're trying to do. Threads are unpredictable, that's why they're called threads! (Silly joke.)

Comment: @MorphingDragon print number in sequential order

Comment: Um, if you want to print the numbers in sequential order don't use threads.

Comment: Why on Earth do you think random, unsychronized threads would run in a sequential fashion?

Comment: @RenniePet in node.js, this for loop should be treated as sequential execution. The order of thread is determined.

Comment: @OldProgrammer http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Introduction, please use my code to search in that article. The author wrote 'C# in a nutshell'. My point is, the output should be at least deterministic/stable.

Comment: @CodeFarmer NodeJS doesn't have concurrency in the same way the C# does. Node fakes it for the main part using an event loop. These are honest to god OS threads with undetermined execution order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reference http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Introduction.

I assume you're talking about the section "Lambda expressions and captured variables", where the author shows a problem with "captured variables", and shows how to avoid that problem with a temporary variable.

But note that the author does *not* claim this will result in the numbers 0 - 9 being displayed in order. What he's claiming (although he doesn't display it) is that each of the 10 threads will display one of the digits 0 - 9. But probably not in order.

That's because threads are unpredictable and are dispatched at the whim of the operating system.